# OpenLayers highlight feature on hover and select on click

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers to display a map and to provide some drawing features. I also added two SelectFeatures to the vector layer I want to draw on. One for highlighting a drawn feature by hover it and one for selecting a feature by clicking on it. 
I used [this](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/highlight-feature.html) example to realize this.

The problem is, that this solution doesn't really work (even in the given example). 
If I draw a new feature I can highlight it by putting the cursor on it but can't select it with a click. (Same in the example, the given features work fine, but after drawing a new one the select-by-click function doesn't react anymore)

Is there any alternative solution to realize this except the official example?

Comment: Yep, the example should work as you except. Please open an issue at https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues

Answer (score 1):

This example [was modified](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/commit/b61cfdb05411f7a1ec4c12187c1767d5ee0c1c46) 4 months ago, editing toolbar was excluded due to described confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get something like this working. You need to activate the controls in a specific order:

```
highlightControl.activate();
selectControl.activate();
dragControl.activate();
```

Hover events aren't handled by the Drag and Pan Controller, so they try the select controller, which doesn't use them either, passing them up to the highlight controller. Similarly, click events aren't handled by the drag controller, but are handled by the select controller. Finally, drag events are dealt with by the drag controller. The last to be activated is the first to be "consulted".